# Parsing a subset of Haskell with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm attempting to write a parser using Parsec that will parse the following:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

plusNat :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plusNat Z     m = m
plusNat (S n) m = S (plusNat n m)
```

For the `data` expression, I have the following parser:

```
parseData = reserved "data" >> DataDefn
         <$> identifier
         <*> parseCnstr `sepBy` reservedOp "|"

parseCnstr = DataCnstr <$> identifier <*> many parseTypeTerm

parseType = buildExpressionParser table parseTypeTerm
    where table = [[function]]
          function = Infix (Function <$ reservedOp "->") AssocRight

parseTypeTerm = TypeVar <$> identifier
             <|> parens parseType
```

However, when I just use this parser on the above text, `parseType` grabs `plusNat` and then errors:

```
"test.hs" (line 3, column 9):
unexpected ':'
expecting "|" or end of input
```

I know what the problem is, it's because `plusNat` is recognised as part of the `dataCnstr`. How do I tell the `dataCnstr` parser to stop when it gets to an unindented new line?

Note that I want to be able to parse the following as well:

```
data ReallyLongData reallyLongTypeVariable
    = ReallyLongConstructor1
    | ReallyLongConstructor2
        reallyLongTypeVariable
        (ReallyLongData reallyLongTypeVariable)

concat :: ReallyLongData a -> ReallyLongData a -> ReallyLongData a
concat = ...
```

Comment: `buildExpressionParser` understands *only expressions*.  You will need to an indentation parser (there's probably a library for that) to slice your input into expressions strings that can then be fed into `buildExpressionParser`.  (You can't really "restrict" what a black-box parser takes except by restricting the input itself.)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a parser which split my input by indented blocks.

Comment: Wait, that doesn't work. I have a function going String -> [String] which splits up indented blocks, but now I can't find a way to parse each block while keeping the SourcePos correct. Using mapM won't work.

Comment: Welcome to the Haskell tag. What a great first Haskell question!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself using [Text.Parsec.Indent](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents-0.3.3/docs/Text-Parsec-Indent.html).

```
parseData = withPos $ <old definition>

parseCntr = (DataCnstr <$> identifier) <*/> parseTypeTerm
```

This ensures that all the type terms are parsed with the correct indentation!